# Notation $K^+$ where $K$ is a cone

Tags: convex-analysis

Is there a common meaning for $K^+$ if $K$ is a convex cone? For instance, it is claimed that $K=K^{++}$ iff $K$ is a closed convex cone (To be clear, I don't want help proving the claim.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps it is the dual cone $\{ y | y^T x \ge 0 \text{ forall } x \in K \}$?

Comment: Yes it is - just saw in my lecture notes. Somehow looked for the last 15 min and just found it after posting

Comment: @copper.hat should I delete the post, it may not be of general interest

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it.